# Code Behind events not triggering using jQuery Mobile

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, code-behind

I'm trying to create a mobile page using ASP.Net and jQuery Mobile. The UI looks great so far, but for some reason controls like asp:DropDownList never fire their selectedIndexChanged events to be handled by my code behind.

I know I should probably be using ASP.Net MVC but I've never done a project in MVC yet, and this project is just a mock up with a short timetable. Is there some way to get the code in the code behind to fire?

I've already tried setting ajaxEnabled to false and settings data-ajax='false' on the master page's form tag.

Comment: Does your dropdownlist have AutoPostBack=true?

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed that did it. Could you post that as an answer so I could accept your solution? I didn't even need to include $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your dropdownlist have AutoPostBack=true?